# how distance and duration actually computed in android google maps direction api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am an android noob and i am exploring android maps api.I am referring this [site](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/).
I can understand everything except the distance and duration retrieval.
The JSON parsing code is given below.

```
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new     ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;
    JSONObject jDistance = null;
    JSONObject jDuration = null;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        /** Traversing all routes */
        for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
            jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");

            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            /** Traversing all legs */
            for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){

                /** Getting distance from the json data */
                jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                /** Getting duration from the json data */
                jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                /** Adding distance object to the path */
                path.add(hmDistance);

                /** Adding duration object to the path */
                path.add(hmDuration);

                jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                /** Traversing all steps */
                for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
            }
            routes.add(path);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
    return routes;
}
```

They are getting distance and duration data for every single leg.The Android docs says , ***distance indicates the total distance covered by this leg*** and ***"duration indicates the total duration of this leg*"**.So my assumption was, during final distance and duration computaion,
all these datum would be added.

This is the final code:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";

        if(result.size()<1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        }

        tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}
```

My assumption went wrong.Here the distance and duration are retrieved for every leg(they are not even stored) and after looping through every route and leg ,finally the textview is set to those variables(distance and duration) and it gives the overall distance and duration.

***So my question is how the overall distance and duration are computed without any manual mathematical operations,while we have parsed those objects corresponding to all individual legs?***

Comment: Hi @ady, i am going with same requirement which you had, and i checked your code is working perfect, its able to get overall distance and duration from "Legs" Array, where "Legs" array "distance" object and "duration" object giving us expected overall time and duration Excluding "Steps" Array, then which problem you had faced that time ?

Comment: The code works fine, but I wanted to understand how exactly the api works as I wrongly assumed its working.

Comment: you mean if we use this code, then we will not find any issue in near future, for getting Distance and Duration, Right ?

Comment: This is not my own code .I have also mentioned the site from where I have used it.So I can't vouch for any issue in future.But I believe, it didn't gave me any issue when I used it at that time.

Comment: Ok, No problem, Thanks, Adi.

Answer (score 0):

use distance matrix api to get the actual distance and time . see the bellow link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

Comment: what is the difference between directions api and distance matrix api?

Comment: distance matrix api provides only distance and time but directions api provides routes (leg steps details )between two location.